# Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class calling NSArrayController's add

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have two classes A and B with a 1:n relationship from A to n B's. In A there is relationship attribute bs (not ordered) and in B there is the a relationship attribute.

A and B actually are NSManagedObject's automatically generated from the project's Core Data model.

In a NSViewController I have an ArrayController and a cell based NSTableView through which I need to show and manage b's.

The ArrayController has:

1. Mode: Class
2. Class Name: B
3. Content set bound to a.bs

Each column of the table is bound to Array Controller arrangedObjects.b_attribute

The table shows the b's as expected and I can edit them.

Problems arise when try to add a new b.

The controller has a button and its action is bound to Array Controller add: method.

Unfortunately, when I press the button, I get the following error:

```
error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer 
on NSManagedObject class 'B'

CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated 
initializer on NSManagedObject class 'B'
```

Digging StackOverflow I have found that the problem may be related to creating managed objects using:

```
... = [[B alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
... = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
```

Since I don't explicitly create b objects, I don't think this is the case,  but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ArrayController:

Mode: Entity Name

Entity Name: B

Prepares Content: YES

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. Tks, anyway.

Comment: Is mode of the array controller set to "Entity Name"?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this issue out as follows:

1. ArrayController linked into the code as bsController
2. the button starts a method for adding new B:

   - (IBAction)newB:(NSButton *)sender {

   B *b = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"B"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

   [_bsController addObject:b];
   }

It works, properly creating an empty row in the table.